# FTP Move / Rename / Copy files between directories

Tags: ftp, total-commander

I have a */ABC* folder with files. I need to move them to parent folder.

Example: In the Apache */htdocs/backup/* folder I have files. I want to quickly move/copy them into */htdocs*

I am using Total Commander FTP and also ISP (Network Solutions) online FTP manager.
Both will not move the file.

TC will bailout with:

> Remote transfer failed - probably NOT
>   supported by server!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Total Commander FTP log trying to perform [RETR and STOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) - Transfer a copy of the file, and going back to the supported features FTP server's response:

```
FEAT
211-Features:
 EPRT
 EPSV
 MDTM
 PASV
 REST STREAM
 SIZE
 TVFS
 UTF8
211 End
```

I see that those commands are not supported:

```
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
RETR 404.html
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 404.html (12474 bytes).
1:STOR 404.html
1:425 Failed to establish connection.
```

**Result:**

1. TC cannot move files between folders
   (the second window does not allow to
   display the same connection - but it
   makes new one - I don't know if this
   has some effect)
2. Netsol File Manager does not allow
   to move files to parent folder. I
   tried multiple ways to name the
   parent folder in the bottom input
   field without success

Comment: Netsol File Mangager works with absolute path starting with slash, e.g.: "/htdocs/"